# How to make blocked wait of connect() API in Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets

In my client program (c++) I am trying to connect server machine through socket using connect() API. I want to make a scenario that my client application is in blocked wait (ie return ETIMEDOUT errno after a long time). But connect() API is returning with success or failure only. It is not waiting. What should I do to make connect() API in blocked wait.

Comment: How do you determine that the `connect()` is not blocking?

Comment: By default, if you haven't made the socket non-blocking, all operations on the socket (including connecting to a host) may be blocking.

Comment: I am not saying connect is not a blocking api. My question is how to make a test scenario that the connect() is in waiting. What to in server/client for that?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have set the socket to non-blocking, you are in fact blocking, it's just that the `connect` is woken up quick enough.

If you want to test for timeout, just unplug for a short while the network cable of the server.

Or, alternatively, the network cable of your own machine, but mind you that this would also disrupt name resolution and you may not even reach to that specific `connect`.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound back to front, but put the socket into non-blocking mode, issue the connect(), then call select() with your timeout. If select() times out, there's your connect timeout. If it selects the socket as writable within the timeout, call connect() again to complete the connection, then put the socket into blocking mode and proceed with your I/O. Check for errors at every step of course.

Note that you can only use this technique to reduce the default timeout of about a minute, not to increase it; and of course if you are getting immediate connection refusals there will be no waiting at all: you can't change that.

Comment: Why do you think that if the OP does not observe a timeout now he will observe one following your procedure?

Comment: Just curious - why do we need to call `connect` again when socket is reported as writable? Isn't the connection already established and calling `connect` again will result in error?

Comment: @MaximSkurydin It's admittedly a very long time since I wrote this kind of code but that's what the man pages, Stevens, etc., used to say when I did it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to experience a `connect` with a failure of `ETIMEDOUT`, you can make a special server that listens for connections but never accepts them. When your client connects to that dummy server program, it will sooner or later time out.

Of course, this assumes that the socket you created in the client is *not* made non-blocking.

Comment: `socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);`
`bind(socket..);`

`listen();`
`while(1) {usleep(xx);} // for getting ETIMEDOUT ?`

`for(count)`
`accept();`
but i am getting success as return for connect().

Comment: @dday Try set the listen queue to zero (`listen(0);`). Or to one, and try to connect with two clients.

Comment: tried both. But connect() client returns success (0) in clients.:(

Comment: @dday You sure `connect` returns `0`? Have you close standard input? That's the only way you could get `connect` to return `0`.

Comment: This is untrue. The TCP/IP stack will complete the connections and place them on the backlog queue. You can't set the backlog queue to zero: you get the platform minimum, which in my experience is at least 5. And whether you get a timeout or a connection refusal when the backlog queue fills is system-dependent.

Comment: connect() returns either 0 or ECONNREFUSED in ubuntu10.04.. in all cases. Badly confused..